# QGIS 3.22.5: how to start the tool "Transect"

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, geometry, toolbox

I am using QGIS 3.22.5. I am relatively new to the GIS world.
I would need to create transects along the coastline shape. Anyway, I do not know how to start the tool Transect. In other words, searching vector>geometry tool I do not see any transect tool.
So, I ask how to start such tool.

Sorry if this has been already asked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run `Menu Processing > Toolbox` to open the Processing Toolbox. This is the place to find all tools, algorithms etc. available in QGIS. Just type the name of the tool to filter for it.

This is a very handy way to find any tool, be it those available in menus as well as those which are not.

[image]

In case the menu `Prcoessing` is not available, activate it in Menu `Plugins`, search for `Processing` and activate the respective plugin.

[image]

Comment: Thanks but... is there a way to set the distance between any transect? E.g. 10 meters or 30 meters and so on

Comment: This is another question... you should ask another question. But transect tool creates lines at vertices, so you should create vertices in regular intervals, e.g. with densify.

Answer (score 0):

I use Autocad to draw sections along an alignment but in QGIS you can use the tool 'Points along geometry', it generates points with their angle value at a specified distance.
Once the point layer is available I use another tool 'Geometry by expression' with this short script

```
make_line(
          project($geometry,10,radians("angle"-90)),
          project($geometry,10,radians("angle"+90))
          )
```

If you do not need a separate layer you can add another one inside the styling panel using the same script in Geometry Generator
I hope it helps